# Starting with the 1st (ith) element in an array, how can I remove the i+1 element if it is greater than or less than the ith element?

Tags: python-3.x

I have an array, for example A = [110, 109, 108, 115, 107, 115, 106, 105, 115, 115, 105].
Starting at A[0] I want to keep the next element A[i+1] if A[i]-6 < A[i+1] < A[i]+6. So in my example all of the 115's should be removed. When I try using for or while loops, I get index out of range. I assume because A[i+1] doesn't exist. Is there a clever way to do this?

```py
g = 6; Au = []; 
while i < len(A):
    if (A[i+1]-g < A[i] < A[i+1]+g):
        Au.append(A[i]) 
    else:
          pass
    i+=1
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: `if it does not satisfy 6 < A[i] < 6`. There is no number which satisfies that condition!

Comment: Do you mean you want to *keep* it -- not remove?

Comment: Yikes, yes.. sry will edit again Keep it and remove what does not satisfy

Answer (score 1):

Simplest:

```
b = [a[0]]

for x, y in zip(a, a[1:]):
    if abs(x - y) < max_diff:
        b.append(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list comprehension that does what you're asking:

```
A = [110, 109, 108, 115, 107, 115, 106, 105, 115, 115, 105]
g = 6
Au = [
         A[i] 
         for i in range(len(A) - 1) 
         if (A[i+1] - g) < A[i] < (A[i + 1] + g)
     ]
```

But this is roughly the same as your current code, compressed into a single line - except that it goes to `len(A) - 1` (thus avoiding an index out of bounds error), not to `len(A)`. Adding this `- 1` to your `while` loop should make your code work properly:

```
while i < len(A) - 1:
    if (A[i+1]-g < A[i] < A[i+1]+g):
        Au.append(A[i]) 
    else:
          pass
    i+=1
```

Comment: May want `A[i +1] for ...` instead of `A[i] for ...`. EDIT: Actually, it's hard to tell which OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can zip A with a shifted version of itself and iterate over those pairs to avoid excessive indexing:

```py
A = [110, 109, 108, 115, 107, 115, 106, 105, 115, 115, 105]
g = 6

Au = [A[0]] + [b for (a, b) in zip(A, A[1:]) if a - g < b < a + g] 
print(Au)
```

```
[110, 109, 108, 105, 115]
```